# Do async call before rendering data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, jsx

My Asyc call is running after the data is rendered I tried running my Asyc call inside constructor and even inside componentDidMount but nothing worked.

**My db structure..**

[image: Firebase Real time database]

**My query in jsx file**

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    Firebase.database().ref('/' + i).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        value[i] = snapshot.val().state;
    });
}
console.log(value);
```

The issue is I want to load images according to the data in the database inside my react native app.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.parent}>
    // This is only one child
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child} id='1' onPress={(event) => this.getState(event, '1')} activeOpacity={1}>
      <Image style={styles.img} source={value[1]} /> // This line is not outputting any image because the array is empty
      <Text style={styles.title}>LED 1</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    // I have 6 child and want to keep the states separate for all
</View>
```

GetState function

```
getState (event, BtnId) {
    value[BtnId] = this.state.mode_1 ? require('./img/on.png') : require('./img/off.png')
    Firebase.database().ref(BtnId).update({
        'state': value[BtnId]
    });     
}
```

If you want more details plz let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advised to do an async call before rendering, So the proper approach is to start the async call in `componentDidMount` and use a flag from the local state to run a spinner or a loading indicator until the async call resolves or rejects.

For React hooks do the async call in `React.useEffect` and in a similar way toggle the value of the local state hook to render the spinner or the data conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify resolve this by setState.

```
async componentDidMount () {
const imageUrl = await yourAsyncProcess()
this.setState({imageUrl: imageUrl})
}
```

And render it with your updated state

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.parent}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child} id='1' onPress={(event) => this.getState(event, '1')} activeOpacity={1}>
      <Image style={styles.img} source={uri: {this.state.imageUrl}} /> // This line is not outputting any image because the array is empty
      <Text style={styles.title}>LED 1</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: I want to keep track of 6 components check my comments in my question

Comment: Write a child components with a function to update image source throught state. Set ref for this . When your async done, call this update function to update your child image data

Comment: Is there any way that nothing should be rendered before the data is loaded?

Comment: I dont think it is a good idea, For do that in essence you must be lock JS thread. And you know, a react native application just have only one JS thread. 

You can "render nothing" like by return null in render if (your async not yet ready)